# Can't open sheet from excel using OLEDB into DataGridView? (_XLNM & $)

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

It seems that I can't open some excel [sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4HgO.png) to be imported to my datagridview.

These are the [list of my sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYnME.png).

Here are my codes.

The code below is my connection string. I am using OLEDB 12.0

```
        public static void ReadExcel(ComboBox cboSheet)
    {

       try
       {
           OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
           openFileDialog.Filter = "Excel Files| *.xls; *xlsx";
           openFileDialog.ShowDialog();

           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(openFileDialog.FileName))
           {
               OleDbcon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + openFileDialog.FileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'");


               OleDbcon.Open();

               DataTable dt = OleDbcon.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

               OleDbcon.Close();

               cboSheet.Items.Clear();

               for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
               {
                   String sheetName = dt.Rows[i]["Table_Name"].ToString();
                   sheetName = sheetName.Substring(0, sheetName.Length - 1);
                   cboSheet.Items.Add(sheetName);
               }
           }

       }

       catch (Exception e)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());

       }

    }
```

THe code below is for importing the sheets to my combobox, that when once selected will change the datagridview including the column and rows.

```
    public static void cboSheetSelected (DataGridView dataGridView1, ComboBox cboSheet, ComboBox cboColumn)
     {
         try
         {
             OleDbDataAdapter oleAdapt = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + cboSheet.Text + "$]", ExcelMethods.OleDbcon);


             DataTable dt = new DataTable();

             oleAdapt.Fill(dt);

             dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
             cboColumn.Items.Clear();

             foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
             {

                 Console.WriteLine(column.ColumnName);
                 cboColumn.Items.Add(column.ColumnName);

                 FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\brandon\sample.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                 StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
                 sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);

                 sw.WriteLine(column.ColumnName);
                 //sw.WriteLine(column.Table.TableName + "" + "sample");

                 sw.Flush();
                 sw.Close();

                 //Console.WriteLine(column.Table);
             }

             foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
             {
                 foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine(item);
                     FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\brandon\sample.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                     StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
                     sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
                     sw.WriteLine(item);

                     sw.Flush();
                     sw.Close();
                 }
             }

         }

        catch (Exception e )
         {
             MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
         }

     }
```

Now, why is it that I can't open some sheets?

I can open sheets:

**Consolidated**

**Distribution**

**Domestic**

**Financials**

**Organization**

**Production**

**Quality**

just fine.

I can't open sheets that have **special characters** like "*comma and dollar signs*".

Refer to the this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYnME.png).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edited:

Excel makes hidden sheets inaccessible to users. They are called `_xlnm_$_FilterDatabase` .

It seems that there's something wrong with my code in the last revision, so I'll ***update*** it.

The reason why I can't access said sheets was because they contained spaces and have the special characters "$" and " **'** " <--- ***apostrophe***.

The results of the sheet names were this.

> xlnm_#_FilterDatabas
>
> xlnm_#_FilterDatabas
>
> xlnm_#_FilterDatabas
>
> xlnm_#_FilterDatabas
>
> xlnm_#*FilterDatabase*
>
> xlnm_#_FilterDatabase_1
>
> xlnm_#_FilterDatabase_1
>
> xlnm_#*FilterDatabase*
>
> xlnm_#_FilterDatabase_2_
>
> xlnm_#*FilterDatabase*
>
> xlnm_#_FilterDatabase_3_
>
> xlnm_#*FilterDatabase*
>
> 'AR Aging$
>
> 'By Brands - SMS$
>
> 'By Brands$
>
> 'By Territory or Channel$
>
> Consolidated
>
> Distribution
>
> Domestic
>
> Financials
>
> Organization
>
> Production
>
> Quality
>
> 'Working Capitals$

It was like this because I've used this code: `sheetName = sheetName.Substring(0, sheetName.Length - 1);` and I've ignored all the sheet names with "$" by using this

```
    if (!dt.Rows[i]["Table_Name"].ToString().Contains("FilterDatabase") && !dt.Rows[i]["Table_Name"].ToString().EndsWith("$'"))
{
}
```

Specifically the `dt.Rows[i]["Table_Name"].ToString().EndsWith("$'"))` so that it can ignore sheets with "$" signs on it therefore making the sheets with *spaces* inaccessible.

I've used this code to resolve it:

```
 sheetName = sheetName.Replace(@"'", "");
 sheetName = sheetName.Replace("$", "");
```

By using the code above,the sheetName called `'By Territory or Channel$` will be turned into just `By Territory or Channel`.

So when they'll be referenced, it would look like this.

```
  OleDbDataAdapter oleAdapt = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + sheetName + "$]", ExcelMethods.OleDbcon)
```